# Sort html content with pagination in ascending and descending order using javascript

Tags: javascript

sorry if this question is asked  before i am new in js so please help me .This is script of sorting html content in ascending and descending order it works so well but i used this with pagination then on every page i have to select order of ascending and descenting i want it if i sort name as ascending order then on each page name will be displayed on ascending order..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
        var rows = tbody.rows,
            rlen = rows.length,
            arr = new Array(),
            i, j, cells, clen;
        // fill the array with values from the table
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].cells;
            clen = cells.length;
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
        });
        // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
        }
    }
</script>


            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Name</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc1 = 1;">Address</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Contact No.</th>

            please help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and modify it to work properly (we should skip `th` headers):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var people, asc1 = 1,
    asc2 = 1,
    asc3 = 1;
window.onload = function () {
    people = document.getElementById("people");
}

function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
    var rows = tbody.rows,
        rlen = rows.length,
        arr = new Array(),
        i, j, cells, clen;
    // fill the array with values from the table
    for (i = 1; i < rlen; i++) { // *** i = 1 to skip th headers 
        cells = rows[i].cells;
        clen = cells.length;
        arr[i-1] = new Array(); // *** i-1
        for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
            arr[i-1][j] = cells[j].innerHTML; // *** i-1
        }
    }
    // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
    });
    // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
    for (i = 1; i < rlen; i++) { // *** i = 1
        rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i-1].join("</td><td>") + "</td>"; //*** i-1
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the modified parts of code are indicated by `// *** ` symbols